# Alternative set theories?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question

Is there a version of set theory that allows the existence of a set that does **not** admit the empty set as a member? I.e., reject the axiom $A\cup \emptyset = A$

Comment: All set theories AFAIK admit the existence of sets that do not have the empty set as a member.  However the "axiom" $A \cup \emptyset = A$ doesn't have to do with $\emptyset$ being a member of $A$.  In short, I can't tell what you are asking here.

Comment: @hardmath: the axiom of OP is simply $\forall A\,\,\, \emptyset\subset A$.

Comment: @hardmath thanks. That helped.

Comment: But $∀A \emptyset \subset A$ is not an axiom ... It follows from the definition of "emptyset" and form the definition of set-inclusion. Thus, we have to reject one of them.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA could you define the null set as the set of cardinality 0?

Comment: What would the empty set be in another theory anyway?

Comment: In some development of set theory [see Enderton,*Elements of Set Theory*,p.18] there is the **Empty Set Axiom**; thus we can "skip" it. But, see [Empty set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_set): "the axiom of e.s can be shown redundant in either of two ways: There is already an axiom implying the existence of at least one set. Given such an axiom together with the axiom of separation, the existence of $\emptyset$ is easily proved. In the presence of urelements, it is easy to prove that at least one set exists, viz.the set of all urelements. Again, given separation, the empty set is proved."

Comment: @GitGud same as in regular set theory, but I thought that all sets must admit the null set as a member. Perhaps the null set is not really an element like the others, so I am just confusing myself.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I see, so any non-trivial set theory must include the null-set as a member of all sets.

Comment: Not every set admits the null set as an element. The empty set is such example. $\{\{\varnothing\}\}$ is another.

Comment: **NOT** "member" but subset ...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA excellent, thanks to you and GitGud...I think i see how this works now. Thanks!

Comment: From comments above, it appears that I was mistaken in treating the null set as an element, not a possible subset. It appears to be logically inconsistent to have the null set excluded as a subset for all but the "empty" universe. Thanks again to all the commenters.

Comment: I will post an "answer" to this question. Feel free to post your own formal response and I'll accept one of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider a new relation $\mathbin{\in'}$ among sets, defined by $x\mathbin{\in'}y$ iff $x\in y$ OR ($y$ is empty AND $x=y$).  Note that the original relation $\in$ can be recovered from this $\mathbin{\in'}$ by: $x\in y$ iff $x\mathbin{\in'}y$ AND $y\mathbin{\not\in'}y$ (this uses the axiom of Foundation, which guarantees in particular that $y\not\in y$).

If we interpret this relation $\mathbin{\in'}$ as a belonging relation among sets, then there is no set which is empty-in-the-$\mathbin{\in'}$-sense: it has been replaced by an atom $o$ which satisfies $o\mathbin{\in'}o$ (and it is the unique set with this property).

Now we can axiomatize set theory for the $\mathbin{\in'}$ relation: indeed, take the axiomatization of ZFC and replace every occurrence of "$x\in y$" by "$x\mathbin{\in'}y$ AND $y\mathbin{\not\in'}y$", and add two further axioms which say that (1) for all $x,y$, if $y\mathbin{\in'}y$ and $x\mathbin{\in'}y$ then $x=y$, and (2) if $y$ is such that there is no $z\neq y$ with $z\mathbin{\in'}y$, then in fact $y\mathbin{\in'}y$ (equivalently, these axioms can be formulated by saying that "$x\mathbin{\in'}y$ iff $x\in y$ OR ((there is no $z$ such that $z \in y$) AND $x=y$)" where $\in$ has been replaced in the right hand side of the "iff" in the same manner as in the axioms of ZFC; this is logically equivalent to (1) and (2)).  It is then easy to see that the original ZFC set theory can be recovered from this ZFC′ by defining $x\in y$ iff $x\mathbin{\in'}y$ AND $y\mathbin{\not\in'}y$.  So both theories are equiconsistent (they are co-interpretable).

So yes, this provides an "alternative set theory" in which there is no such thing as the $\mathbin{\in'}$-empty set: instead, the axioms guarantee the existence of $o$ such that $o$ is the unique $\mathbin{\in'}$-element of $o$.  (Furthermore, even if we interpret $\mathbin{\in'}$ as $\in$, I think the axioms of ZFC′ minus Foundation′ and the axiom (2) are consistent with ZFC minus Foundation, or something like that.  So it's not even so wildly "alternative".)

Of course, this set theory is profoundly uninteresting.  It just stupidly replaces the empty set by a self-containing atom by changing the $\in$ relation.  But it *can* be done.